# Working with NSPredicate for Unit Testing in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have following test class, that get data from remote server and trying to check it for nil:

```
import XCTest
@testable import DogYears

class DogYearsUnitTests: XCTestCase {
    var resData: Data? = nil

  func testInfoLoading(){

    let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FahimF/Test/master/DogYears-Info.rtf"
    HTTPClient.shared.get(url: url) { (data, error) in
      XCTAssertNil(error)
      XCTAssertNotNil(data)
        self.resData = data
    }

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resData != nil")
    let exp = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: self, handler: nil)
    let res = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [exp], timeout: 5.0)
    if res == XCTWaiter.Result.completed {
      XCTAssertNotNil(resData, "No data recieved from server for InfoView content")
    } else {
      XCTAssert(false)
    }

  }
}
```

It does work, but i wonder why NSPredicate Not working. You see, changing `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resData != nil")` to `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resData == nil")` have no effect, and test still passed, why it's passed even for this `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resData == nil")` ?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: @matt its not related to question at all

Comment: Yes, it is. It's about the order in which code is executed. — Also you should be mocking / stubbing networking calls; there is no need to test the real network, we know what that does.

Comment: @matt var does set in closure after delay, but predicate should evaluate after time interval I did set.

Comment: You're just rolling dice. You need to create the expectation _before_ you start networking, and _fulfill_ it _inside the asynchronous block_. Read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations.

Comment: @matt i may assume that block when i set expectation is executed before networking complete (because it asynchronous operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test passed with let `predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resData == nil")` because it is true at start, as soon as request is not performed simultaneously) And your timer doesn't helps you. And also it is passed with `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resData != nil")` due timer, your request have time to fetch data.

Here is the simple example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations

You can rewrite your test like this, where instead of your request I run a code in another thread, I think it is easier to read:

```
class DogYearsUnitTests: XCTestCase {

    var resData: Data? = nil

    func testInfoLoading(){

        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Download apple.com home page")

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
            self.resData = Data()
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        // Wait until the expectation is fulfilled, with a timeout of 10 seconds.
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
        XCTAssertNotNil(resData)

    }
}
```

Comment: great, how to rewrite it so predicate statement would affect test case?

Comment: I did rewrite it, hope it will helps you